# Displaying gutters when more than one row/column is used by an element in CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

In a CSS grid one can use the `grid-column-gap` and `grid-row-gap` properties to set the gutter width between elements.

If an element uses more than one grid area, however, the gutters aren't shown.

Is there any way to get the gutters to show if an element takes up more than one grid area? I'm looking for something visually similar to this:

```css
div{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 140px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  background:#eee;
  row-gap: 10px;
  width:140px;
}
div>div{
  background: white;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
  This is ONE element
  </div>
  <div>
  split in two
  </div>
</div>
```

But rather than having to use two elements, I am hoping to split one with CSS

**EDIT:** Here's some context.

I am looking to split some text and perhaps images into 'pages', so that anything that overflows one page ends up on another. Think MS Word.

A JavaScript solution would work for adding pages when one overflows, but would be nigh impossible to get working *well* given how may user actions and edge cases there are to handle (e.g. if the user deletes a character, how do I know if the text would now fit on one page, or if the second page is still necessary?).

So what I am looking to do is to extend the 'page' as the user writes (with a page as the background) and put CSS breaks in the element that make the text 'jump over' the gaps in the pages.

Here's a picture to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: Not with gutters. You'll need another method.

Comment: @Michael_B Oh, that's quite a shame... Do you have any suggestions for how it could be done?

Comment: If you could provide more context and other details in your question, maybe we can help you.

Comment: @Michael_B Of course. I've added a bit of context, with some great art to help with visualizing the problem

Comment: @DividedByZero thank you for providing the context, it communicates your goal clearly. Which is, you want to determine if the user typing, has reached the end of the page height. Then, do something like add another div or object for the user to continue typing. What's missing is, how have you tried to approach this?